# Can't seem to use GPU with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I'm trying to get tensorflow to talk to my GPU so I can model my neural networks quicker. I've installed tensorflow-gpu and cuDNN using pip and I already had the driver and cuda installed. I've checked for if tensorflow can see my GPU using:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib 
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

for which it returned:

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 5916901003862901746
, name: "/device:GPU:0"
device_type: "GPU"
memory_limit: 4848943104
locality {
  bus_id: 1
  links {
  }
}
incarnation: 16957123506888322798
physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6GB, pci bus id: 
0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1"
]
```

so I guess it found my GPU. And a check for cuda with :

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.test.is_built_with_cuda())
```

returned True so it's found the cuda installation. But when I try to initialize it with:

```
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()                                
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
sess.run(tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer())
```

I get an invalid arguement:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device for operation assert_greater_3/Assert/Const: 
Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:0' because no supported kernel 
for GPU devices is available.
Colocation Debug Info:
Colocation group had the following types and supported devices: 
Root Member(assigned_device_name_index_=-1 requested_device_name_='/device:GPU:0' 
assigned_device_name_='' resource_device_name_='' supported_device_types_=[CPU] 
possible_devices_=[]
Const: CPU 

Colocation members, user-requested devices, and framework assigned devices, if any:
  assert_greater_3/Assert/Const (Const) /device:GPU:0
```

and then it falls back to using my CPU.

I don't quite understand the error message other than I'm missing kernel. I tried looking for the error online but nothings came up. Has anyone else run into something like this and know a way round?

Comment: If it is at all possible, I recommend ignoring `TF 1.x` and instead switching to `TF 2.X`, preferrably `2.5`.

Comment: @Chi which version of TensorFlow are you using?

Comment: Hi Swaroop, it's tf 2.5

Comment: after `import tensorflow` do you get any warnings or messages?

Comment: Hi Dominik, no it's all fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Captain Trojan for the comment. I was just trying to adapt the code for TF2.x (with somewhat limited coding experience) and found if I ran an upgrade using:

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

the error disappeared although I still can't get tf to talk to my GPU and not sure if its a TF1.x/TF2.x problem. I ran:

```
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
 a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
 b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
 c = tf.matmul(a, b)

sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))

print (sess.run)
```

and it returned:

```
Device mapping:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce 
GTX 1060 6GB, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1

<bound method BaseSession.run of <tensorflow.python.client.session.Session 
object at 0x00000217323C0B50>>
```

so it was able to map something my GPU.

But I can't get my original code:

```
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column('image', shape = [255, 255, 3])]
    classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(feature_columns = feature_columns,                                                     
                                            hidden_units = [128, 64, 32, 16],                                                      
                                            activation_fn = tf.nn.relu,
                                            n_classes = 3,
                                            model_dir = 'model',
                                            optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1, decay=1e-6),        
                                            dropout = 0.1)
classifier.train(input_fn = train_input_fn, steps = 1000)                                                                        
result = classifier.evaluate(input_fn = val_input_fn)
print(result);
print('Classification accuracy: {0:.2%}'.format(result['accuracy']))
```

to talk to my GPU still. It falls back to my CPU still. Anyone know if I'm calling my GPU device wrong maybe?

Comment: Is this supposed to be answer to your question?

Comment: I guess it answered the error message but not the original problem - should I open a new thread for it?